# type '_MapStream<QuerySnapshot, List<RoomModel>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<RoomModel>' in type cast

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This is what code look like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhPnY.png

and RoomModel looks like this.

```
RoomModel.fromFirestore(Map firestore)
  : roomId = firestore['roomId'],
    price = firestore['price'],
    location = firestore['location'],
    street = firestore['street'],
    description = firestore['description'],
    gender = firestore['gender'],
    userId = firestore['userId'];
```

Error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRuxo.png

Any help or suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Please edit your question to show how `firestore` is initialized.

Comment: [Please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=DO%20NOT%20post%20images%20of%20code%2C%20data%2C%20error%20messages%2C%20etc.)